# soapAction de NuSoap en PHP puro

Tags: php, webservice, soap

he intentado por todas partes lograrlo pero me ha sido imposible, no quiero hacer uso de NuSoap y lo único que me falta para cuadrar todo con el SoapClient de PHP es poder indicar el soapaction tal como lo puedo montar en el NuSoap.

En NuSoap lo tengo así:

```
$result = $this->proxy->call('getData', array($data), 'http://tempuri.org/','server.com.co/service.asmx/getData', false);
```

Ahí funciona perfectamente noten que debo poner el soapaction como tipo REST "server.com.co/service.asmx/getData"

En PHP puro lo he intentado así:

```
        $header = new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/','server.com.co/service.asmx/getData',$data,false);
        $this->client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
        // Se realiza la solicitud
        $result = $this->client->getData($data);
```

Pero me retorna error.
Alguien me pueden indicar si hay una forma de logar esto.
Gracias

Comment: Si vas a consumir debes usar soapclient y si vas a crear uno es soap server por tanto  usa  http://php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Hola Hector, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla). ¿Podrías indicarnos cuál es el error que te retorna? Quizás pueda servir de punto de partida para ver qué es lo que está fallando. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, Gracias por las prontas respuestas, @JackNavaRow entiendo como consumirlos, quiero es saber como poner el soapaction y que me funcione de igual manera que con NuSoap. Alvaro muchas gracias por la bienvenida me retorna error 403, con el NuSoap si consume bien el servicio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, despues de varios intentos logre dar con el truco, imagino es algo simple y tonto, pero prefiero dejar la solución acá para los que como yo se puedan llegar a atascar un poco.

```
$result = $this->client->__soapCall('getData',array($data),array('soapaction' => 'server.com.co/service.asmx/getData'));
```

Como ven con el metodo soapCall nativo de SoapServer de PHP como tercer parametro se coloca un array indicando el soapaction que se desea ejecutar, en el caso mió debo especificarlo como un llamado get del metodo que quiero usar tambien.
Muchas gracias.